# Python regex reference conflicting with substitution number

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I'm taking a beginning Python course, and am having problems trying to do a regex substitution.

The question states: Write a substitution command that will change names like file1, file2, etc. to file01, file02, etc. but will not add a zero to names like file10 or file20.

Here's my solution:

```
re.sub(r'(\D+)(\d)$',r'\10\2','file1')
```

As you can see, the 0 is messing with my \1 reference. Can anyone help me with an easy solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
print re.sub(r'(\D+)(\d)$',r'\g<1>0\2','file1')
```

Don't ask.. just do the \g<#> thing and it'll work fine in python.  Other languages have the same issue:

http://resbook.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/regex-with-back-references-followed-by-number/

Answer (score 0):

dont know python, but in your regex you just want one digit and not two

for the match you can do it like this

```
.+[^\d]\d$
```

test1 will match
test1 will not match

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

@sdanzig has the correct answer, but if you insist to ask, it is actually a documented feature:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Read the last paragraph for `re.sub()`.

> In string-type repl arguments, in addition to the character escapes
>   and backreferences described above, \g will use the substring
>   matched by the group named name, as defined by the (?P...)
>   syntax. \g uses the corresponding group number; \g<2> is
>   therefore equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such
>   as \g<2>0. \20 would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a
>   reference to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'. The
>   backreference \g<0> substitutes in the entire substring matched by the
>   RE.